# ARP issue with VLAN on VMWare Workstation

Tags: ubuntu, vlan, netplan

I have two vm in WMware Workstation 17 Pro.

They are connected like this (by the way the OS is Ubuntu 22.04)

```
Ubuntu1 -- vlan 10 -- Ubuntu2
```

But they can't connect each other:

[image]

So I check source traffic with `tcpdump`

ARP generate correctly in `vlan.10` and forwarding `ens33` that vm's pysical interface and ARP format transport to `Unknown hardware, Unknown protocol`.

And, suddenly destination can't get anything with `tcpdump`. I think ARP does not approach destination:

[image]

Can these ARP formats cause problems with vlan communication? If it's another problem, how can I solve it to communicate?

##### My ubuntu vlan setup:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have VMware Workstation V17 here and use it. Can you please clarify (Screen Shot) where you see VLAN in VMware?  It has NAT network connection default and very simple to set up.

Comment: well I use host-only network. Wait a second I will edit my question to upload my ubuntu vlan setup

Comment: Host Only blocks everything except Guest to Host connectivity. Do not use Host Only for normal use.

Comment: oh I just test vlan configuration on vmware, not using in my home network so I use host-only and I upload my vlan setup screenshot on text

Comment: Like I said Host Only blocks all connections except Guest to Host. You need to re-think.

Comment: So you mean that host-only blocks vlan communication between virtual machines?

Comment: Yes.   You are not using the correct connectivity approach at all.

Comment: Ok So if I change my vmnet host-only to bride or nat. Then my issue will figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VLAN is outside of VMware (VMware does not use VLAN internally).

So your VLAN is in your router.

Bridged Connection is the only thing that makes sense now.

Host Only will block connections between guest machines.

Comment: Thx to help me. Just change my vmnet host-only to brideges. It working correctly